# How to set a Custom tab field's value?

Tags: docusignapi

I have to Populate Custom field value from System using Docusign Api, Is there any api available ?

So far i did following things

1. created a custom field and put it on Document like below image.

[image: screenshot of custom tab]

2. Used

   POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/fields

It gave an error:

[image]

Is there any way to populate custom field value before send to particular signer?
Need a help.

Comment: are you planning to add Custom Field on a document and also prepopulate this field value at the time of envelope creation?

Comment: @AmitKBist Thanks for your comment!!
Want to populate field value at the time of envelope Creation. 
I found the using https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=Envelopes&operations=create api and passed value in it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for using DocuSign! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your own questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, unfortunately, the term "custom field" is often used for two different features in the DocuSign system:

**Envelopes can have metadata fields.** These fields are not shown to any recipients. Their full name is `Envelope Custom Fields`. They are managed by using the Admin Tool. See the screenshot of the Admin tool's navigation panel:

[image: Admin Tool navigation panel]

`Envelope Custom Fields` can be set by the sender of the envelope (or via the API). They are visible on the Cert of completion and can be accessed via the API.

As far as I can tell from your question, this is NOT what you're doing.

**Tabs can have customized settings.** Since tabs (API terminology) are called fields in the web user interface, once they are customized, some call them Custom Fields. But the better term is `Document Custom Fields`

They are managed at the account level, so you can also use the Admin Tool to manage them.

**API for populating Document Custom Fields** You can set their values when you create the envelope.

Here is a create envelope example for setting a Document Custom Field which is a drop down field. The envelope is being created from a template.

Note how the template roles are set, and for the role which has associated tabs, just the tab value is being set.

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "templateId": "77b6fbef-1448-4ac3-819f-253a9e1cb08e",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "clientUserId": "1000",
            "email": "signer@example.com",
            "name": "Larry Kluger",
            "roleName": "signer",
            "tabs": {
                "listTabs": [
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "Custom Drop down",
                        "value": "Option 2"
                    }
                ],
            }
        },
        {
            "email": "cc_person@example.com",
            "name": "Susan Kluger",
            "roleName": "cc"
        }
    ]
}
```